# Example of a complex transcendental number?

Tags: complex-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Researching transcendental numbers I have only come across ones with a transcendental real part. I can't think of any which are pure imaginary or are not based on a real transendental number, t, of the form $t + ni$. Any ideas?

Edit: After some excellent responses, I now have another thought see [Complex transcendentals not known in component form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1866475/355433)

Comment: Ok, I have found one to add to the collection: $\sqrt{i\pi+\sqrt{i\pi+\sqrt{i\pi+\sqrt\cdots}}}$ thanks to zeraoulia rafik

Comment: @lhf True, should've been more explicit: I'm looking for ones not based off real transcendental numbers

Comment: From Gelfond-Schneider, if $\alpha \ne 0,\ 1$ and $\beta$ are algebraic numbers with $\beta$ irrational, then $\alpha^{\beta}$ is transcendantal. You can construct many complex examples from this.

Comment: @JoelCohen Nice, thanks for sharing that!

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281480/is-a-complex-number-with-transcendental-imaginary-part-transcendental.

Comment: Note that if $a+bi$ is transcendantal, then at least one number among $a$ and $b$ is transcendantal.

Comment: Regarding your edit, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We have $a + bi$ is algebraic iff $a$ and $b$ are algebraic.

Therefore, if $a + bi$ is transcendental then at least one of $a$ or $b$ is transcendental.

So, all complex transcendental numbers are "based" on real transcendental numbers.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. So for any transcendental number, $t$, $Im(t)$ or $Re(t)$ (or both) must be transcendental.

Comment: @Nonsematter, yes.

Comment: Just a comment. It's still conceivable that there exists a complex number $a + bi$ for which we can prove $a + bi$ is transcendetal, but we don't know which of $a$ and $b$ is transcendental. I think that would be very interesting.

Comment: @6005: I guess $z=\pi e^2+\pi ei$ might be an example of this.  It is transcendental because $\frac{\mathrm{Re}(z)}{\mathrm{Im}(z)}=e$ is transcendental, but it is not known whether $\pi e$ is irrational, and I guess the same for $\pi e^2$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Instead of guessing about $\pi e^2$ we can use $\pi+e+\pi e i$, since both $\pi+e$ and $\pi e$ are definitely of unknown status. But at least one of them is transcendental, because otherwise the roots of $x^2-(\pi+e)x+\pi e$ would be algebraic.

Comment: Thanks Jonas and Henning, those are both nice examples.

Comment: @HenningMakholm's observation $(x-c)(x-d)=x^2-(c+d)x+cd$ shows that whenever $c$ and $d$ are two transcendental numbers, then either their sum $c+d$ or their product $cd$ (or both) must be transcendental as well. It is trivial, of course, to find examples where only one of these two is transcendental.

Answer (score 7):

Real transcendental number: $\pi$, $e$, $\ldots$ 
Imaginary transcendental number: $i\pi$, $ie$, $ie^\pi$ , $i\pi^e (\text{suspected to be true but not yet proved})$ $\ldots$ 
Complex number with transcendental real and imaginary parts: $\pi+i\pi$, $e+i\pi$, $\pi+ie$, $e+ie$, $\ldots$

Moreover, a purely imaginary transcendental number can be $\ln(-1)$, following from the equation $e^{i\pi}=-1$ and in which case, we have to extend the domain of definition and hence the range of the *natural logarithm*.

Comment: Is it known that $\pi^e$ is transcendental?

Comment: @JonasMeyer It is not proven but generally mathematicians believe it to be true. You can check this link ... http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/pickover/trans.html

Comment: Transcendental would be the safest bet, but is there a particular reason to believe that particular number is transcendental? That blog post doesn't provide any evidence. As Gerry Myerson once said, "every number not known to be algebraic is suspected transcendental."

Comment: @JonasMeyer I totally agree with what you say. Accordingly, I have edited my answer because the expression *looks* **too beautiful** not to be a transcendental number.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I think you're conflating "reason to believe" with "mathematical proof."

Comment: @djechlin: What is a reason to believe?

Comment: @JonasMeyer the axioms of ZF or the integers seem consistent, which i believe since we've been doing a lot of math without any apparent problems.

Answer (score 3):

I've always been intrigued by
$$i^i=e^{-π/2}$$
(at least its principal value) and you will note that
$$i^{i^i}=e^{(iπ/2) e^{-π/2}}$$
does not fall into the facile category of $a+ib$ where $a$ and $b$ are well-known transcendental numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$i^{i+n}$ is transcendental for integer $n$.